# how to check if attribute name exists in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to check if particular attribute exists in dynamodb? I.e I have file like geo.ip in dynamodb how to check if geo.ip exists in dynamodb? Can anybody tell what is the correct to check using aws cli?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you want to check for the existence of an item **attribute** or for the existence of a **table**.

You can use `aws dynamodb list-tables` to get a list of tables. If you need one with a particular name, just `grep` it:
`aws dynamodb list-tables | grep geo.ip`
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/list-tables.html

There is no way to check if an attribute exists for an item without actually reading the data: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/get-item.html
You can use `--attributes-to-get` option to retrieve (or not) only the attribute that you're interested in.